# Working with millions of MySQL rows

Tags: mysql

I am working on a way to record click times for each user on my website.

I have currently 600,000+ records when trying to think of a way to go about this.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clicktime` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=686277 ;
```

I will have to do ten of these searches per page. My blog shows a snippet of ten pages at once.

```
SELECT time 
FROM clicktime 
WHERE `page` = '112'
  AND `user` = 'admin' 
ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

The call that looks like it's getting me, is the `WHERE page = '112'`

How can I make this work faster, it is taking up to 3 seconds to pull each call?

Comment: Is your table mostly read, or mostly updated?

Comment: It is mostly read. Never updated, only added to.

Comment: Downvoter care to help us all avoid your wrath in the future?

Answer (score 2):

Though there are multiple things that could be better here (the time being a bigint for instance), the thing that will help you on short term is just to add an index on your `user` field.

Comment: Thank you! Adding an index to the user and page field sped it way up!

Comment: You should read up a bit on indexes, but for this case, the best index would probably be a combined index for page and user, but there is a downside (size, insertion speed) you might notice when adding more indeces.

Comment: If you do create a multi-column index, put the one with the highest cardinality first. For example, if there are more pages than users, put pages first.